# Modifying gitignore to svnignore updates after initial syncronization in SubGit

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I'm running SubGit for BitBucket Server, installed as an add on within the BitBucket website.

I see the following:

> Translation Settings
>   **Settings in this section could only be altered before synchronization is ran for the very first time.**
>
> Translate file attributes Translate changes in .gitattributes files to
>   svn:eol-style and svn:mime-type Subversion properties.
>
> Translate Ignores Translate changes in .gitignore files to svn:ignore
>   Subversion property.

Is there really no way to stop this after I've set everything up?  Some developers on my team still plan on using SVN and don't want these changes sync'd over.

I see the ignores property in this documentation: https://subgit.com/documentation/config-options.html#svn but have no idea how or where to set that, or if it is possible via the BitBucket add in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "Settings in this section could only be altered before synchronization is ran for the very first time" statement means that those particular settings should be set prior to the initial translation, they cannot be changed on the fly. If the mirror has already been established and now you need to change these settings -- there is no other way to do it but re-translate the repository from the very beginning.

As for the configuration settings in the document -- some of them are equivalent to the settings in the add-on UI, namely, `svn.minimalRevision` is present in UI as "Minimal Revision" field in "Translation Settings" section, `translate.eols` is present as "Translate file attributes" and `translate.ignores` is equivalent to "Translate Ignores" in the same section. It doesn't make sense to add these configuration settings as they already present and are being set in the UI.

However, the rest can help if you need to set an option that is not present in web UI. To set an option just add it to the mapping configuration on the "Branches Mapping" tab. By default, there is only one `[svn]` section and only mapping options present in the configuration, but you can add any section and any settings you need (excluding those already present in UI, of course). For example, if you need to set, say, `svn.httpSpooling` and `translate.otherProperties`, just add `[translate]` section and the options to the configuration:

```
[svn]
# Options below (trunk, branches, tags, shelves) define correspondence between Subversion
# directories and Git references. Depending on the actual Subversion project layout and whether
# all or only some of the branches have to be mirrored, these options might need to be adjusted.
#
#  Generic mapping syntax is:
#    <Subversion-Path-Pattern>:<Git-Reference-Pattern>
#
#  Subversion paths are relative to the URL defined by the svn.url option.
#
#  For more details refer to http://subgit.com/documentation pages.
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*

httpSpooling = true

[translate]

otherProperties = true
```

Note, however, that some of the settings must also be set prior to the initial translation and cannot be changed on the fly after it.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Am I correct in thinking that ignores are being constantly synced as they change because of this setting?  It looks like if I add a gitgnore property it becomes an SVN ignore property.  If I retranslate, would this stop?  My dev team just doesn't want folder property conflicts because of this.

Comment: On a related note, I believe my commits in Git are not displaying the correct author because I don't have svn user names and passwords setup.  We're a really small shop with known passwords, so storing in the plain text passwords file described in the following url would be fine.  How do I do this from the add in?  It almost sounds like it needs to be checked in to the repo in a subgit folder?  That can't be right?  My team, unfortunately, has been less than receptive to this whole idea, and adding a directory of passwords to the project would not be popular.

Comment: yes, if "Translate Ignores" is switched on, `.gitignore` is being constantly translated to `svn:ignore`, so if a gitgnore property is added, it's translated to SVN ignore property. If you switch this setting off and retranslate, then yes, it `.gitignore` and `svn:ignore` won't be kept synchronized anymore.

Comment: Regarding the commits authors -- do you mean that incorrect authors are being set in the Git commits that have been translated from SVN? If so, that's happening due to incorrect authors mapping: the add-on relies on information provided on "Authors Mapping" tab when sets commit or revision author name. Authors mapping is just a list of SVN usernames and corresponding Git identities, like "johndoe = John Doe <johndoe@example.com>.  When the add-on translates data, it searches for a match in authors mapping and sets author name accordingly.

Comment: Here are the details on authors mapping: https://subgit.com/documentation/authors-mapping.html

Comment: Also, you might face with opposite situation, when svn username, that the add-on uses to connect to the SVN server, is being set as translated SVN revisions despite correct authors mapping is provided. In this case, you would need to enable `pre-revprop-change` hook in the SVN repository, see chapter 3 of the authors mapping guide above.

Comment: And regarding the "Specifying a username and a password" guide -- it doesn't work for the SVN Mirror add-on, it's only applicable to SubGit command line tool. With the add-on, you don't need to make any changes in the repository, everything should be set in the add-on web UI.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't had a change to try this out yet today, but I also had not noticed that authors mapping guide at all.  I suspect that will help.  The issue I'm seeing is that SVN displays the commiter of git commits as the username and password specified in the connection section of the add it.

Comment: If so, you definitely need to enable the `pre-revprop-change` hook in the SVN repository, it will resolve the issue and author in SVN will be set according to the authors mapping.

Comment: By the way, I'like to ask, how did you find that documentation page you mentioned (doc.subgit.com/display/SG/Specifying+a+username+and+a+password )?

Comment: Thanks so much.  You've been really helpful.  Subgit has also made my life much, much easier.  I'm fairly sure I googled to get to that link, but I cannot find the exact search in my history.

Comment: So, I created a new repo with the translate file attributes and translate ignores unchecked.  I also have [translate] otherProperties = false.  The good news, I do believe I am no longer changing merge info and svnignore in the SVN repo.  However, every checkin results in the top level directory properties being touched and marked as modified.  Is there a way to stop this?